# Playsound module raise an error for non specified files in Python

Tags: python, tkinter, playsound

Ok so the **problem is** : When I click on the upload button and I don't specify a file during the askopenfilename and I leave directly with the cross an error occurs 'playsound exception' that I didn't manage to catch with try/except statement otherwise I don't know how to prevent this or fix the problem ...

code :

```
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter import ttk
from playsound import playsound 
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename 
root = Tk()
root.geometry('800x600')


frame1 = Frame(root,width='100',height='50',bg='black',borderwidth=1)
subframe1 = Frame(root, bg='black', width='660', height='351')
labelframe1 = Label(frame1,text='go to frame1',fg='orange',bg='black')

frame2 = Frame(root,width='100',height='50',bg='blue')
subframe2 = Frame(root, bg='blue', width='660', height='351')
labelframe2 = Label(frame2,text='go to frame2',fg='orange',bg='blue')

buttonframe1 = Button(subframe1, text="firstbutton",fg='orange')
entryframe1 = Entry(subframe1)
comboframe1 = ttk.Combobox(subframe1,values=['option1','option2' ,'option3'])
comboframe1.set('default option')


buttonframe2 = Button(subframe2, text="secondbutton",fg='orange')
entryframe2 = Entry(subframe2)
comboframe2 = ttk.Combobox(subframe2,values=['option1','option2' ,'option3'])
comboframe2.set('default option')


uploadbutton = Button(root,text='upload',fg='orange')


frame1.place(x=0,y=0)
labelframe1.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.5,anchor=CENTER)
frame2.place(x=0,y=140)
labelframe2.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.5,anchor=CENTER)
uploadbutton.place(x=0,y=240)

def change_frame1(*args):
    subframe1.pack(side=RIGHT)
    subframe2.pack_forget()
    buttonframe1.place(x=0,y=0)
    entryframe1.place(x=0,y=40)
    comboframe1.place(x=0,y=80)
    
def change_frame2(*args):
    subframe2.pack(side=RIGHT)
    subframe1.pack_forget()
    buttonframe2.place(x=0,y=0)
    entryframe2.place(x=0,y=40)
    comboframe2.place(x=0,y=80)

def upload(*args): 
   
        file = askopenfilename(filetypes= [('MP3 Files', '*.mp3')])
              
        if file is not None: 
            playsound(file)

frame1.bind('<Button-1>', change_frame1)
labelframe1.bind('<Button-1>', change_frame1)
frame2.bind('<Button-1>', change_frame2)
labelframe2.bind('<Button-1>', change_frame2)
uploadbutton.bind('<Button-1>',upload)


    


root.mainloop()
```

Error :

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\user\project\pythonproject\venv\Lib\site-packages\project.py", line 327, in <lambda>
    soundbutton = Button(root, text="upload",
command = lambda : upload())
  File "C:\Users\user\project\pythonproject\venv\Lib\site-packages\project.py", line 341, in upload
    playsound(file)
  File "C:\Users\user\project\pythonproject\venv\Lib\site-packages\playsound.py", line 35, in _playsoundWin
    winCommand('open "' + sound + '" alias', alias)
  File "C:\Users\user\project\pythonproject\venv\Lib\site-packages\playsound.py", line 31, in winCommand
    raise PlaysoundException(exceptionMessage)
playsound.PlaysoundException:
    Error 292 for command:
        open "" alias playsound_0.39688356388365387
    The specified command requires an alias, file, driver, or device name.  Please supply one.
```

Comment: Have you verified that `file` is not an empty string before calling `playsound(file)`?

Comment: I don't think `file` can be `None`, but it can be `''` so why don't you try to change to `if file: 
 playsound(file)`

Comment: Bryan Oakley
 no but the problem is solved I think

Comment: – 
Delrius Euphoria
 Works fine ! But it's normal if my whole program is slowed down when I click on upload ? (not the sample code above but on a bigger program of about 600 lines not so huge but still longer than what I showed above) I can't switch between frame without it being laggy(very slow to display the content of other frames)

Comment: If I am not wrong, `playsound` will block the thread too